# cannot import wsgi from gevent

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to run my heroku app locally so that I work on it when I don't have internet. I am able to run the app completely fine on the Heroku website after pushing it however I can't run it locally. When I run `heroku local` I get this error in particular:

```
11:17:19 web.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
11:17:19 web.1   |    File "app.py", line 24, in <module>
11:17:19 web.1   |      bottle.run(server='gevent', host='0.0.0.0', port=os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
11:17:19 web.1   |    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 3127, in run
11:17:19 web.1   |      server.run(app)
11:17:19 web.1   |    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 2907, in run
11:17:19 web.1   |      from gevent import wsgi, pywsgi, local
11:17:19 web.1   |  ImportError: cannot import name wsgi
11:17:19 web.1   Exited with exit code 1
```

Please note I have downloaded gevent using `pip install gevent`
Also I am on a mac version 10.13.5 in case that is relavent
Thanks

Comment: Make sure your pip and python version are same. Else you should be using `pip3 install gevent`. Also try import `gevent` and see if that works in python or not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gevent.wsgi` was deprecated for years and was finally removed in gevent 1.3. There's an open [bottle bug](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/issues/1065) for this problem. Some of your options are:

1. Use a different WSGI server. You can directly use gevents wsgi server with `python -m gevent.pywsgi my_module:my_app`. Or try gunicorn
2. Downgrade to an older gevent
3. Patch the bottle sources to not have the broken import. `gevent.wsgi` simply did `from gevent.pywsgi import *`, so anywhere you see `wsgi.Thing` just replace it with `pywsgi.Thing`.

Comment: the easiest solution is `pip install -U 'gevent~=1.2.2'`